# MarkLogic Corb how to configured to enable a web UI

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-corb

I'm interesting how to Provide real-time metrics for the Corb job as it progresses. configured to enable a web UI and HTTP service, in order to view the current job stats and progress, pause/resume, and adjust thread counts. I can be able to track performance, job stats, and errors over a period of time in order to facilitate charts for track details about various CORB jobs being run. Any samples how to setup and see on Web UI. Thanks so much.

```
###full.properties
XCC-CONNECTION-URI=xccs://admin:admin@localhost:8000/devdb
THREAD-COUNT=16
BATCH-SIZE=1
URIS-MODULE=full-full-uris.xqy|ADHOC
PROCESS-MODULE=full-process.xqy|ADHOC
COMMAND-FILE=RESUME
CONNECTION-POLICY=RANDOM
ERROR-FILE-NAME=updated-errors.log


###full.sh
java -cp /opt/corb/lib/corb-2.4.0.jar:/opt/corb/lib/marklogic-xcc- 9.0.12.jar -DOPTIONS-FILE=full.properties com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable the [JOB-SERVER-PORT](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#JOB-SERVER-PORT) specifying either the specific port or a range of potential ports to use.

i.e.

```
JOB-SERVER-PORT=8003-9000
```

When you start the CoRB job, it will log the URL of the job server with the port that is being used when it starts.

> The job server will bind to a port from the configured port number(s). By default, if the JOB-SERVER-PORT option is not specified, a job server is not started.
>
> When a port is specified and available, the job server URL will be logged to the console with both the UI http://: and metrics URL http://:/metrics. (grep for string com.marklogic.developer.corb.JobServer logUsage)

Comment: Can I run multiple corbs with same port 8020?

Comment: Out of the box, a CoRB job expects to bind to a port for exclusive use. So, for normal executions, no. However, if you wanted to write a little java, you can execute CoRB programatically. An example of a single CoRB JobManager bound to a port that tracks multiple CoRB jobs in the UI: https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/blob/master/src/test/java/com/marklogic/developer/corb/ManagerDemo.java#L97